# C# application communicating with C++ server

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, compression

How to scheme where:
 - Client is on C# side (sending request to server)
 - Server is on C++ side (Linux) (responding to client request and closing)

And communication between that nodes are via TCP, i want to apply SSL encryption and compression methods, I don't worry about C# side but i don't want code much in C++.

Is any fast way to add encryption and compression layer to that communication or pack/encapsulate that communication into other communication with encryption and compression?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be HTTPS communication between them. That would probably be the fastest way. Regardless, whatever approach you take, you'll have to write equal amounts of code on both sides.

Comment: Maybe consider google's protocol buffers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908140/googles-protocol-buffers-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you're going to use SSL, then why do you need an "encryption layer"?  I'm assuming you haven't made the service yet, look at doing either an http server or soap.  If you go with soap then consuming it based on the wsdl file in C# is fairly easy.