# C# Tcp sending data to server? Id or Reflections?

Tags: c#, reflection, authentication, tcp, stream

first of all I couldn't find a title that would explain exactly what I'm trying to do here.

What I can't seem to understand to do is how do I send a message from my tcp client to my server with multiple parts to that message? for example:

*(msgID = 1 / username: vincent / password: 123admin) <-- this is the full message.

As you can tell I'm trying to make a login system. Now back to the question, my problem is that I want to maybe add each section to an Array, so that when the array is received I can split apart each section without having to check through the string for the message id ect..

Also I heard of reflections? I guess it's like calling a method remotely over the network? Maybe this method is better for my situation e.g. CheckLoginDetails(int ID, string username,string password) and this method return true or false back to the client if the details are correct? If you think this method is more suitable please I would love to learn how to do this! I used to use Unity3D and there networking involved something like this.

Here's where I am now:

Server:

```
private void HandleClient(TcpClient c)
    {
        byte[] packetIDData = new byte[2];
        c.GetStream().Read(packetIDData, 0, 2);
        ushort packetID = BitConverter.ToUInt16(packetIDData,0);

        Console.WriteLine("PacketID: " + packetID.ToString());
        switch (packetID)
        {
            case 0: 
                break;
            case (int)RequestTypeEnum.login:
                break;
            case (int)RequestTypeEnum.logout:
                break;
            case (int)RequestTypeEnum.ping:
                break;
            case (int)RequestTypeEnum.update:
                byte[] data = new byte[4];
                c.GetStream().Read(data, 0, 4);
                int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                data = new byte[length];
                c.GetStream().Read(data, 0, length);

                List<byte> backData = new List<byte>();
                backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)0));
                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(response)));
                backData.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response));
                c.GetStream().Write(backData.ToArray(), 0, backData.ToArray().Length);
                break;

        }
        c.Close();
    }
```

Client:

```
List<byte> updateData = new List<byte>();
        updateData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)RequestTypeEnum.login));
        updateData.AddRange(StringMethods.MakeString(username));
        updateData.AddRange(StringMethods.MakeString(password)); // this needs encryption
        client.GetStream().Write(updateData.ToArray(), 0, updateData.Count);

        client.GetStream().Read(new byte[2], 0, 2);
        string answer = StringMethods.ReadString(client);
        switch (answer)
        {
            case "success":
                return true;
            case "failed":
                return false;
            default:
                return false;   
        }
```

Comment: Consider [*Protocol Buffers*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908140/googles-protocol-buffers-in-c-sharp) or similar existing encodings. The implementations will use reflection to "magically map the data to types". The only remaining step is to add framing, as required. A basic frame might be type,length,data..,checksum. The type provides the dispatch to the right type for [Protocol Buffer] decoding and the length specifies how much more to complete the frame. Keep reading everything and then send it off when a "complete frame" is read: don't make the reading logic different for each type!

Comment: Alternatively, consider a text-base transmission format like JSON. It's less compact, a bit slower, but also a heck of alot easier to debug - i.e. can create trivial client to frame arbitrary requests. If using interfaces then it would be possible to trivially switch between JSON or Protocol Buffers and both encodings could use the *same* DTOs.

Comment: Have a look at WCF operation and data contracts